# HTTPS not working on first load (private tab or new computer)

Tags: magento2.3, https, caching

I have noticed that when I open our website (voltbike.com) in a private window or on a computer which hasn't visited it yet, often the website doesn't load with HTTPS.

It is only once I refresh the page that it loads correctly.

Does anyone have experience with this and where should I look to investigate this problem?

We're running Magento 2.3.5-p1 with Securi firewall & caching and no Varnish.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
I just set both the secure and unsecure store url to 'https://'.
*Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Base URL / Base URL (Secure)*